# Hive Server2,Beeline not able to understand

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

Q1 : What is Server2 in Hive?

Q2 : What is the use of jdbc or odbc in Server2? For What purpose server2 is used with jdbc or odbc?

Q3 : If i want to connect with Hive server2 to jdbc or odbc, how I can connect? Can I connect in my cloudera which is single node? Guide me how to connect with it?

Q4 : How to connect with Beeline in Cloudera. The commands of Beeline are same or there is any difference. How to connect Beeline with jdbc and odbc?

Please help me regarding these questions. I searched on internet but unable to understand it.. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Please find answers below:

A1. HiveServer2 is simply the version 2 of the Hive Server. The enhanced Hive server is designed for multi-client concurrency and improved authentication that encourages clients to connect through JDBC and ODBC rather than thrift protocol directly

A2. JDBC/ODBC is the standard recommended way to interact with SQL engines through programming languages. Apart from interacting with Hive using command line i.e. beeline, clients can interact programmatically or external applications like Tableau / Qlik etc which needs the corresponding JDBC/ODBC drivers. The process should be the same whether its a single node or distributed cluster.

A3. Please refer Cloudera documentation on how to setup and execute Hive commands using JDBC/ODBC. Check the below links
http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/other/connectors/hive-jdbc/latest/Cloudera-JDBC-Driver-for-Apache-Hive-Install-Guide.pdf

A4. Check the link for complete example - http://hadooptutorial.info/hiveserver2-beeline-introduction/

Hope that helps!!

Comment: I have a cloudera in pseudo mode. I downloaded Virtual box and then downloaded cloudera file and the things are pre installed. I am unable to connect with beeline

Comment: the error which I got [cloudera@quickstart ~]$ beeline
2016-09-18 20:10:18,995 WARN  [main] mapreduce.TableMapReduceUtil: The hbase-prefix-tree module jar containing PrefixTreeCodec is not present.  Continuing without it.
Beeline version 1.1.0-cdh5.7.0 by Apache Hive
beeline> show databases;
No current connection
beeline> !connect jdbc:hive2//hostname:10000
scan complete in 5ms
scan complete in 6272ms
No known driver to handle "jdbc:hive2//hostname:10000"
beeline> 
Can u pls help me. I don't know how to install because hadoop ecosystem is already pre-installed. I am new in Hadoop.